# Toolbar appearing on top of layout when using RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I have a top and bottom Toolbars and an ImageView between them:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <omar.myapp.app.viewpager.ImageViewPager
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar_top"
        android:layout_above="@id/toolbar_bottom"
        android:id="@+id/mainViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that the bottom toolbar is appearing on top of the ViewPager:

[image]

The image is correctly below the top toolbar, but is appearing behind the bottom toolbar.

Does anyone know why the image is going behind the bottom toolbar rather than staying above it?

Answer (score 1):

Hiding behind **view** is done in **Relative** and **Frame Layout** only.

use Linear Layout that is solve your problem ....

have look on your edit xml...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <omar.myapp.app.viewpager.ImageViewPager
        android:id="@+id/mainViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/splash"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

</LinearLayout>
```

output of this code:-[image]

enjoy coding............

Comment: what you want both toolbars on top ?

Comment: No, I want the imageview to be between them and not behind the bottom toolbar